Approximately merge/sketch union of $n$ sorted lists in subquadratic time
Given $n$ sorted lists $L_1,\ldots$ each consisting of at most $n$ distinct values $L_i=\{l_{i,1},l_{i,2},\ldots\}$, that is there are $O(n^2)$ distinct values in total. Is it possible to extract $O(n)$ 'well-distributed' values $v_1,\ldots$ from the set of all input values $\bigcup_{i}L_i$ quickly? That is we want that

$|[v_i,v_{i+1}]\cap\left(\bigcup_{i}L_i\right)|=O(n)$ for all $i$ and
every item of $\bigcup_{i}L_i$ lies between two such $v_i,v_{i+1}$

in subquadratic (in $n$) time, say near linear time: $O(n\cdot\mathrm{polylog}(n))$?
This question can be rewritten in terms of search trees: Given $n$ balanced seach-trees $T_1,\ldots$ each tree $T_i$ representing the up to $n$ values $L_i$. Is it possible to 'sketch' some balanced seach-tree $T$ of $\bigcup_{i}L_i$, by only outputting the first $\log(n)$ levels of pivot elements of $T$ in near linear time $O(n\cdot\mathrm{polylog}(n))$?
Some comments regarding this question:

We assume that accessing $l_{i,j}$ and comparing values takes $O(1)$ time
A clear upper bound of this problem is $O(n^2\log n)$ by building and sorting $\bigcup_{i}L_i$ and outputting every $n$-th element, or conversely building the seachtree $T$ completely, and outputting its first $\log(n)$ levels of pivot elements. The main difficulty is to not inspect every element $l_{i,j}$ but rather exploit that the lists are already sorted.
A trivial lowerbound is the output-complexity of the values $v_1,\ldots$, but other than that I was unable to come up with anything, or find anything in literature regarding this (rather specific) problem
What if we relax some of the restrictions, say we are fine with $O(n\cdot\mathrm{polylog}(n))$ values $v_i$ such that $|[v_i,v_{i+1}]\cap\left(\bigcup_{i}L_i\right)|=O(n\cdot\mathrm{polylog}(n))$? What about $O(n^{1+\varepsilon})$?

Sketch of Answer for $O(n^{3/2}\mathrm{polylog}(n))$
Claim: Given $n$ sorted lists of at most $n$ items. In $O(n\log n)$ time one can determine a value $v$ such that $$\frac{1}{4}\left|\bigcup_iL_i\right|\leq\left|\left\{l_{i,j}\in\bigcup_iL_i\middle|l_{i,j}\leq v\right\}\right|\leq \frac{3}{4}\left|\bigcup_iL_i\right|.$$
Proof: In $O(n\log n)$ time we can determine a value $v_i$ for every list $L_i$ such that $v_i$ splits $L_i$ in half. These $v_i$ form a list $V$ of $n$ sorted values. Weigh every such $v_i$ by $|L_i|/2$. Select the value $v$ out of these $v_i$ which splits the total weight of $V$ in half. But then one quarter of the total values lie to the left of $v$ and one quarter of all values lie to the right of $v$, which concludes the proof.
We can recursively apply this splitting $\bigcup_iL_i$ in a balanced way a total of $8\sqrt{n}$ many times, resulting in $O(\sqrt{n})$ elements $v_1,\ldots$, such that $|[v_i,v_{i+1}]\cap\left(\bigcup_{i}L_i\right)|=O(n^2(3/4)^{\log_2(8\sqrt{n})})= O(n^2(1/2)^{\log_2(\sqrt{n})})=O(n^{3/2})$ in total time $O(\sqrt{n}\cdot(n\log n))=O(n^{3/2}\mathrm{polylog}(n))$.

You can sample $c \cdot n \log n$ random elements, sort them, and then select every $c \log n$-th element. We argue that each $[v_i, v_{i+1}]$ has at most $2 c n$ elements with high probability. Otherwise, the expected number of sampled elements in $[v_i, v_{i+1}]$ is at least $2 c \log n$. By https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Multiplicative_form_(relative_error), the probability that we sampled $\le c \log n$ elements is at most $e^{-c \log n / 8} = n^{-c/8}$. Taking a union bound over all intervals, we get $n^{1 - c/8}$ error probability, which we can make arbitrarily small
